# ActiveRecord has two association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

What is the best way to achieve a has two association with activerecord?

I have a Team and Game models.  Each Team will have_many games `@team.games`.  A Game will have two teams `@game.hosting_team` and `@game.opposing_team`.

I started out with two `belongs_to/has_one` associations but then `@team.games` would only return their home games.

The other option I can think of is using a HABTM and use a validator to ensure there are only records.  The only thing missing is keeping track of the home team.  It seems like I need a has many through association but I'm not exactly sure...

Thanks for your help.

This is an example of how the two has_many associations look.  The problem here is I would have to call `team.games` and `team.opponents` to get a full list of their games

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :games
  has_many :opponents, :class_name => "Team"#, :foreign_key => ""
end

class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :team, :class_name => "Team" #, :foreign_key => "team_id"
  belongs_to :opponent, :class_name => "Team" #, :foreign_key => "opponent_id"
end
```

I'd like something like this but this obviously isn't how belongs_to works.

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :games
end

class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :hosting_team
  belongs_to :opposing_team
end
```

My desired api would look like this.

```
@team.games # return all games home or away
@game.hosting_team # Team
@game.opposing_team # Team
```

Comment: Can you calrify the model's relationships and maybe post your db/schema.rb ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can probably still model it with the bt/ho associations, and set up games as an accessor method on the team instead of as an association:

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  def games
    Game.find(:conditions => ["home_team_id = ? OR away_team_id = ?", id, id])
  end
end
```

Comment: Yeah good idea.  My Team model would have_many :home_games and have have_many away_games.  Then your games method would select both of them.  Thanks this is probably the answer.