# Two associations from the same model possible?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, foreign-keys, associations

I have a model Country (which is the same as 'Team') and a model Match and I am trying to build a scenario where I have a Match record with both home & away teams.

**The models**

```
class Country < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :home_matches, :foreign_key => 'home', :class_name => "Match"
  has_many :away_matches, :foreign_key => 'away', :class_name => "Match"
end

class Match < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :home, :class_name => "Country", :foreign_key => "home"
  belongs_to :away, :class_name => "Country", :foreign_key => "away"
end
```

**The schemas**

```
  create_table "countries", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.text     "bio"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "matches", :force => true do |t|
    t.datetime "matchdate"
    t.integer  "home"
    t.integer  "away"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
```

**Problem**

This works well if I just want:

```
> canada.away_matches
> japan.home_matches
```

But how do I get all matches that a country is playing?

**Update:**

I found the answer in another reply.
[ActiveRecord has two association](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4298487/activerecord-has-two-association)

I have updated my Country model with the following code:

```
def matches
  Match.where("home = ? OR away = ?", self, self)
end
```

Now I can query:

```
> canada.home_matches
> canada.away_matches
> canada.matches
```

And get the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting up the associations in a wrong way.
 Go through this

1. [Single_Table_Inheritance wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_Table_Inheritance), and
2. [single-table-inheritance-and-where-to-use-it-in-rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/555668/single-table-inheritance-and-where-to-use-it-in-rails)

Comment: I see. Skimming through I think its exactly what I need.