# rails post params getting a id not found

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm getting the following error when posting a form: ***Couldn't find Team without an ID***

I have the below post parameters

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "_method"=>"put",
 "authenticity_token"=>"knq4dG1U/5NJxMD6KYxfOpKd3CuOBHRlp6xCwdpwCnQ=",
 "match"=>{"name"=>"latest match",
 "date(1i)"=>"2013",
 "date(2i)"=>"5",
 "date(3i)"=>"19",
 "teams_attributes"=>{"1368967240149"=>{"name"=>"Navi",
 "id"=>"1"}}},
 "commit"=>"Update Match",
 "match_id"=>"2"}
```

Model:

```
team has_many :matchips

team has_many :matches :through => matchips

match has_many :matchips
match has_many :teams :through => matchips
```

Teams Controller:

```
  def create


    @team = Team.find(params[:team_id])  <-----fails here!


    redirect_to @match

  end
```

Form:

```
<%= nested_form_for @match, :url => {:action => "add_team_to_match_post"} do |f| %>
  <% if @match.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@match.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this match from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @match.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :date %><br />
    <%= f.date_select :date %>
  </div>

  <%= f.fields_for :teams, :html => { :class => 'form-vertical' } do |builder| %>
  <%= builder.label "Team Name:" %>
    <%= builder.autocomplete_field :name, autocomplete_team_name_teams_path, :update_elements => {:id => "##{form_tag_id(builder.object_name, :id)}" },:class => "input-small",:placeholder => "Search" %>
  <%= builder.hidden_field :id %>

  <% end %>

  <%= f.link_to_add raw('<i class="icon-plus-sign"></i>'), :teams, :class => 'btn btn-small btn-primary' %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

So i basically have a many-to-many relationship between matches and teams. using nested_form for the matches, but the issue is that it's looking for the association before creating or updating, i want it. I previously done this with a many to one association where the child model would get created when the parent gets created or updated, on this occasion i already have the teams all i'm doing is passing the id and name via the post/put request so i can associate it to that match.

If there is a better way to associate already created entities then please let me know.

Comment: Your `params` doesn't have `:team_id`. Something wrong with your form perhaps?

Comment: could it be the id under `teams_attributes` ? . Also make sure your `routing` is done right. P.S Get a little polite :).

Comment: actually the issue is not getting the value, but its expecting the association to be on there already. so on create it will have 'unable to find teamid=1 for matchid= ' and on updating the match 'unable to find teamid=1 for matchid=1'

Comment: what model is team_id in?

Answer (score 2):

You probably need something like:

```
def add_team_to_match_post

    @match = Match.find(params[:match_id])

    params[:teams_attributes].each_value do |team_attributes|
      team = Team.find(team_attributes[:id])
      @match.teams << team
      team.matches << @match
    end

    redirect_to @match
end
```

Basically, this is iterating through every team in the `teams_attributes` hash and adding it to the match object (since this is a many-to-many)

Comment: Hi, I've done that already but i'm looking for a restful solution within rails, as it's getting messy, ie: there can only be two teams per match.  Is there anything i can do with the create method in 'teams', such as cater for it when its coming from /teams/createnew and one for /matches/2/addteams (ann example)

Comment: If there is a better way to do this please suggest it. So the usecase is, how to add associations (many-to-many) for child elements that have already been created. I'm using autocomplete to search for the team and keeping the id as a hidden field.

Answer (score 2):

After looking at this and asuming in **team_attributes** the key **id** is the id of team.

```
 "match"=>{"name"=>"latest match",
     "date(1i)"=>"2013",
     "date(2i)"=>"5",
     "date(3i)"=>"19",
     "teams_attributes"=>{"1368967240149"=>{"name"=>"Navi",
     "id"=>"1"}}}
```

Do this in controller

```
 team_key = params['match']['teams_attributes'].keys.first
 team_id = params['match']['teams_attributes']['team_key']['id']

 Team.find(team_id)
```

OR

**Another choice is available to do same thing**

If you select team by autocomplete then after selecting team by ajax you can also add hidden field with name **team_id** and it value will be selected team id.

then you can easily access params[:team_id]

---

**Let me suggest you new way of thinking**

what if, if you think **a match belongs to many teams**
 remove middle table

and on match new and edit form select two teams whose match you want to held.

for reference look at this
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

why I'm asking you do this?
The answer is you have to create a match between already existing teams and no need to save match on team save.

But on match save you have to save team.

Hope this cure

Comment: The issue is not accessing the team id, but that it's expecting an association to already be on there. like is said, you do this where the child model belongs to the parent and it's fine, but with this many-to-many i get this error.

Comment: Will you please explain it more efficiently. I did not properly get the point you are disusing. As after reading your question I got that you are not able to get team_id. Now you are talking about some association. As in many_to_many_through association there will be existence of third model. Then what kind of association you missed?

Comment: Sorry, let me explain it cleared. On creating the match with the two teams, it says 'unable to find team=1 for match= '  when i have a team created and i go to edit it and add the two teams it says 'unable to find team=1 for match=1' so rails is for some reason expecting the team to already be associated when the match hasn't been created. why does this work in a one-to-many association where the child only gets created with the parent, but fails when i try to link to models together. hope that helps.

Comment: I've modified my answer above check that if it helps and still there is any confusion feel free to ask.

Comment: No your are doing many to many I'm asking you to do one to many. I think you did not picked the things correctly about **accepts_nested_attributes_for** as you did not mention that in your model. You have to read that article carefully that is explained very well. Still you are getting issues then tell me.

Comment: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: teams.matchship_id: SELECT "teams".* FROM "teams"  WHERE "teams"."matchship_id" IS NULL AND "teams"."id" IN (2)

Comment: yes it should be as teams don't have **matchship_id** column in its table. You are applying wrong query on teams table. Will you please tell what you actually wants to do.

Comment: Simple, I have a MATCH model, which needs to hold relationship for two teams, these two teams already exist. So the use case is, user goes to a Create a MATCH, then they need to search for the Two teams that they want and create the association along with the match. So its easy to see that teams could have many matches, and Matches have two teams.

Comment: if you wants to find two teams having same match id. Then you have to First find Match and then you can find teams for that match.
`match = Match.find(2)` and on second line do this

`teams = match.teams`

Answer (score 0):

change `params[:team_id]` to `params[:teams_attributes][:id]`

Answer (score 0):

`has_many` for Matches <> Teams is an overkill. [Please see this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4298487/activerecord-has-two-association) for mocking a has_two relationship. That would simplify your forms and URLs quite a lot.

Comment: problem is, Teams could have many games. Let's say you want to generate games for a season.